# SonarQube - Can you copy resolved issues db to another sonar instance?

Tags: sonarqube

We have a large corporate Sonarqube instance and a large code base. The greater team has gone through a large number of issues and marked them as resolved, so that we can easily see new issues.

My team wants to run our own Sonarqube instance (for reasons I won't go into) and would like to start with the same issues marked as resolved.
Is this possible without backing up and restoring the entire sonarqube database?

Thanks!
Shawn

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: no.

But you may not need to. The issues page provides date-related filters, so you should easily be able to filter out old issues using the "New Issues" filter. See [this example](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/issues/search#resolved=false%7CcreatedAfter=2015-05-01) on nemo. Note that the interface gives you a few, canned date options, but the date in the URL is easily editable.